# How to connect to an Oracle db using a stored procedures within a Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I need to verify data between and Oracle db and a Microsoft SQL server db to verify that if there differences between the two and then update the Microsoft SQL server with any changes there may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OPENQUERY` with TNS alias already configured in `tnsnames.ora`  file

Comment: this is how I found my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use/create database links. That means that you have to have oracle client installed on your sql server though.

Answer (score 0):

You may configure connection to Oracle as [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.110).aspx) in SQL Server and use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.110).aspx) to synchronize date in SQL Server agent's job, for example. Fetching data from linked server could not the fastest thing in the world, but it is very easy to configure and use.